# Cannot link to Rcpp library in CLion Rcpp project

Tags: c++, r, cmake, rcpp, clion

I'm writing an `R` package that heavily relies on `Rcpp`. However, I'm not satisfied with the quality of writing `C++` source code in Rstudio and I prefer to use CLion.

And here - although I manage to compile the code in CLion and manage to use it correctly later in Rstudio, I would like to have a working executable where I could test and debug from CLion. And this is something I can't achieve.

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.5)
project(SomeProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

# R headers
include_directories(/usr/include/R)
# Rcpp headers
include_directories(~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES *.cpp *.h)

add_library(SomeProject ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(SomeProject /lib/R/lib/libR.so) # this is where my libR is located
```

`library.h`

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace SomeProject {
    Rcpp::List doSomething(Rcpp::List someList);
}
```

`library.cpp`

```cpp
#include "library.h"

Rcpp::List SomeProject::doSomething(Rcpp::List someList) {
    return someList;
}
```

And this works perfectly well. However, if I try to add some executable that calls something from `Rcpp`:

```cpp
#include "../library.h"

int main() {
    Rcpp::List list(0);
    return 0;
}
```

and add executable target to `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
add_executable(SomeProjectExec exec/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SomeProjectExec SomeProject)
```

and then I run this executable, I get the following message:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I've tried linking `Rcpp` library, not only headers, in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(SomeProject ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so)
```

but it resulted in error during build:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRcpp
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong or what am I missing? Appreciate your help in advance!

I'm using `5.4.38-1-MANJARO` OS.

I would like to point out that while I can write some code in `C++`, I have no experience in building `C++` libraries using `CMake` or any other tool.

Comment: One note, I've seen cases in which CMake does not handle the `~` path shortcut well. Consider using the **full** path instead...

Comment: Sorry but that is more or less your self-imposed problem with CMake which unfortunately clashes with how R works.  R _only_ knows `R CMD COMPILE ...` and `R CMD SHLIB ...` etc pp -- and all that is entirely independent of Rcpp.  We never claim or document or suggest using CMake for that very reason.  You can still _edit_ in CLion and build in a shell outside of it.  You will get less semantic feedback.  Again, you need to talk to R Core developers of R about that, not the Rcpp team.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel , thanks for your reply and suggestions. Guess I'll have to do without advanced debugging...

Comment: Yeah. It is what it is.  I sometimes set up code in 'generic' C++ projects (where I get such integration) and in 'glue projects' that deal mostly with the interface for which the existing tools are good.  RStudio is not so bad on fetching error diagnostics etc so I too use it to complement my normal editor.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
# find R headers
execute_process (
    COMMAND bash -c "R CMD config --cppflags | sed s/-I//g"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE rInclude
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

# find Rcpp headers
execute_process (
    COMMAND bash -c "Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()' | sed s/-I//g | sed 's/.\\(.*\\)/\\1/' | sed 's/\\(.*\\)./\\1/'"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE rcppInclude
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${rInclude} ${rcppInclude}")
```

and whatever else you need

Comment: Instead of the second `Rcpp::CxxFlags()` call a much simpler `cat(system.file("include", package="Rcpp"))` and you can then also skip the `sed` dances.